# Forma correcta de llamar a un metodo Async

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buen dia

Les pido una disculpa si el tieulo de la pregunta no es el mas apropiado, pero no se me ocurrio algun otro

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Etoy trabajando con la siguiente dataTble:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es my codigo html de dicha tabla:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="primary">
            <th></th>
            <th hidden class="idRequest">idRequest</th>
            <th>Solicitante</th>
            <th>Dia de solicitud</th>
            <th>Estatus</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Cuando hago click en el boton verde señalado en la imagen con una flecha y un recuadro rojo muestro una subTabla con datos de mi registro. esta accion la reralizo con el siguiente codigo de Jquery:

```
            // Add event listener for opening and closing details
            $('#table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);
                if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {
            // Open this row
                    row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            });
```

A continucion les muestro mi funcion format(row.data()) [Es aqui donde se presenta mi problema]:

```
function format(d) {
    var buttons = '';
    subTable = '<table>'
    getRequeriments(d.request.idRequest).then(data => {
    data.forEach(element => {
        if (d.status == 'En Proceso' && element.fkTypesStatus == 1 &&
            (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()'
                || @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
            buttons = '<button class= "btn btn-success btn-circle realizado" title="Realizado"> <i class="material-icons">done</i></button>' +
                "&nbsp;" +
                '<button class= "btn btn-danger btn-circle noRealizado" title="Rechazar"> <i class="material-icons">close</i></button>'
        } else if (d.status == 'En Proceso' && element.fkTypesStatus == 3 &&
            (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()'
                || @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
            buttons = '<h6 class ="text-success">REALIZADO</h6>';
        } else if (d.status == 'En Proceso' && element.fkTypesStatus == 5 &&
            (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()'
                || @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
            buttons = '<h6 class ="text-danger">NO REALIZADO</h6>';
        }
        subTable += '<tr>' +
                '<th hidden>' + 'ID' + '</th>' +
                '<th hidden>' + 'idReq' + '</th>' +
                '<th>' + 'Numero de parte' + '</th>' +
                '<th>' + 'Pool' + '</th>' +
                '<th>' + 'Estacion' + '</th>' +
                '<th>' + 'SA1' + '</th>' +
                '<th>' + 'SA2 Actual' + '</th>' +
                '<th>' + 'SA2 Solicitado' + '</th>' +
                '<th>' + 'Razon' + '</th>' +
                '<th>' + 'Estatus' + '</th>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td hidden class ="id">' + element.idRequisition + '</td>' +
                '<td hidden class ="idReq">' + d.request.idRequest + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + element.itemNumber + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + element.pool + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + element.station + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + element.SA1 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + element.lastSA2 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + element.currentSA2 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + element.reason + '</td>' +
                '<td class ="buttons">' + buttons + '</td>' +
                '</tr>'
        });

    subTable += '</table>'
    });

    return subTable;
}
```

Esta es la funcion que mando a llamar para obtener los datos de mi sub tabla:

```
async function getRequeriments(idRequest) {
    const requeriments = await $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("getRequeriments", "verRequest")",
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'application/json',
        data: {
            'idRequest': idRequest
        }
    });
    return requeriments;
}
```

Ya habia echo algo similar pero sin utilizar una funcion async, el problema es que cuando lo hago con la funcion async  no me muestra los datos.

Es la primera vez que utilizo este tipo de funciones y la verdad nose como funcionan exactamente, podrian ayudarme con este problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes que tener presente que todas las funciones involucradas en el proceso asincrónico deben o esperar a la promesa o ser `async`.

Si la idea es usar `async/await`, entonces podrías hacerlo así:

```
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', async function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = table.row(tr);
  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    // Open this row
    row.child(await format(row.data())).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

Y también

```
async function format(d) {
  return await getRequeriments(d.request.idRequest).then(data => {
    var buttons = '';
    var subTable = '<table>';

    data.forEach(element => {
      if (d.status == 'En Proceso' && element.fkTypesStatus == 1 &&
        (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()' ||
          @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
        buttons = '<button class= "btn btn-success btn-circle realizado" title="Realizado"> <i class="material-icons">done</i></button>' +
          "&nbsp;" +
          '<button class= "btn btn-danger btn-circle noRealizado" title="Rechazar"> <i class="material-icons">close</i></button>'
      } else if (d.status == 'En Proceso' && element.fkTypesStatus == 3 &&
        (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()' ||
          @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
        buttons = '<h6 class ="text-success">REALIZADO</h6>';
      } else if (d.status == 'En Proceso' && element.fkTypesStatus == 5 &&
        (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()' ||
          @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
        buttons = '<h6 class ="text-danger">NO REALIZADO</h6>';
      }
      subTable += '<tr>' +
        '<th hidden>' + 'ID' + '</th>' +
        '<th hidden>' + 'idReq' + '</th>' +
        '<th>' + 'Numero de parte' + '</th>' +
        '<th>' + 'Pool' + '</th>' +
        '<th>' + 'Estacion' + '</th>' +
        '<th>' + 'SA1' + '</th>' +
        '<th>' + 'SA2 Actual' + '</th>' +
        '<th>' + 'SA2 Solicitado' + '</th>' +
        '<th>' + 'Razon' + '</th>' +
        '<th>' + 'Estatus' + '</th>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td hidden class ="id">' + element.idRequisition + '</td>' +
        '<td hidden class ="idReq">' + d.request.idRequest + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + element.itemNumber + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + element.pool + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + element.station + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + element.SA1 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + element.lastSA2 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + element.currentSA2 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + element.reason + '</td>' +
        '<td class ="buttons">' + buttons + '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
    });

    subTable += '</table>'
    return subTable;
  });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

El hecho de marcar la función como `async` indica que devuelve una `Promise<T>`, donde `T` es tipo del objeto devuelto.

Haciendo tu función `getRequirements` asíncrona, debes esperar el resultado, entonces devolver.
En tu código sí esperas el resultado de `getRequirements`, pero devuelves `subTable` antes de resolver la `Promise`. Por ello, tu función `format` también debe devolver una `Promise` (de tipo `string`).
Para ello, puedes hacerlo de dos formas.

1. Devolviendo explícitamente una `Promise`

```
function format(d) {
    // ...
    let subTable = `<table>`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getRequirements(d.request.idRequest).then(data => {
            // Modificar subTable

            subTable += `</table>`;
            resolve(subTable); // Devuelve subTable como resultado de la Promise
        });
    });
}
```

2. Haciendo la función `format` asíncrona, también.
   Implícitamente devuelve de nuevo una `Promise`

```
async function format(d) {
    // ...
    let subTable = `<table>`;
    const data = await delay(100);
    // Modificar subTable

    subTable += `</table>`;
    return subTable;
}
```

Finalmente, donde estés llamando a la función `format`, *awaitear* el resultado de la función.

```
const handleClickTable = () => {
    // ...
    if (/* */) {
        // ...
    } else {
        format(row.data()).then(result => {
            row.child(result).show();
            tr.addClass(`shown`);
        });
    }
}
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', handleClickTable);
```

Y de nuevo, como siempre, tenemos la versión `async`/`await`

```
const handleClickTable = async () => {
    // ...
    if (/* */) {
        // ...
    } else {
        const tableFormat = await format(row.data());
        row.child(tableFormat).show();
        tr.addClass(`shown`);
    }
}
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', handleClickTable);
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda para aclarar algunos conceptos.